# Does sphinx consider pdf file producer during searching?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, ocr, sphinx

I have my own web application which uses sphinx as search engine, i'm using Readiris as an OCR and i store the searchibul Pdf into the application
Rreadris generates 1.7 pdf version which is indexed
So while searching for Arabic words it doesn't show results but when searching for same pdf/xps file genrated by Word Microsoft it shows relevent results
In both cases i a using pdf_to_text function to take the text and store it
The application is running on Ubento 18

Supposed to give same results whether the producer of pdf dile is Microsoft or Readiris because the word file is even generated by Readiris so it's the same OCR

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.